# Как получить вернувшиеся значения из контроллера?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Я отправляю id из страницы на сервер, ответ приходит - это объект модели, найденный по id, как мне вытащить из него нужный мне элемент (Price)?
Скрипт:

```
 var data = {
    Id: null,
    Name_Product: null,
    Price: null,
    Description: null
}
$.ajax({
    url: '/editpr',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({ id: tested }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    //dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (data) {
        var Price = data.Price
        var newinput = document.createElement('input')
        newinput.className = 'save_inp'
        newinput.id = 'id_save_inp'
        newinput.value = Price
        $('.price').html(newinput)
```

Код контроллера:

```
 public Products Editproducts([FromBody] int id)
{       
  //  Products Product = null;
    DBEntities bd = new DBEntities();
    Products SenMes = bd.Products.Find(id);
    if (SenMes != null)
    {
        Products product = new Products
        {
            Id = SenMes.Id,
           Name_Product = SenMes.Name_Product,
            Description = SenMes.Description,
            Price = SenMes.Price,
            MesAndProduct = SenMes.MesAndProduct
        };
      // Product = SenMes;
        return product;
    }
    return null;
}
```

И вот что я получаю в итоге... [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне избавится от undefined и получить цену, которая будет соответствовать данному id?

Comment: Для начала - определиться, правильно ли приходит и обрабатывается на сервере id продукта. После чего убедиться, что метод возвращает продукт, а не `null`. А затем убедиться, что он правильно (чтобы клиент его мог распарсить) отсылается на клиент.

Comment: Всё происходит гладко, мне необходимо только узнать, как можно вытащить элемент из объекта

Comment: Если бы всё происходило "гладко", то и проблемы бы не было. Раз в `data.Price` не попадает нужно вам значение - значит, jQuery не в состоянии распарсить ответ от сервера. Хотя бы приведите пример возвращаемых сервером данных.

Comment: Вот значения, которые возвращаются prntscr.com/dmsxwr - SenMes prntscr.com/dmsy1m - Price

Comment: А эти обрывочные скриншоты данных откуда? Я подразумевал данные, которые приходят на клиент, в браузер. Вопрос в том, как они упаковываются (в JSON, или в XML, или ещё во что) и как это выглядит по прибытию на клиент. По виду полученных данных должно стать понятно как получить доступ к `Price`.

Comment: Может сперва нужно распарсить ответ?

Comment: Объявление полей класса Product можно увидеть? возможно у вас не public это поле, тогда надо написать метод возвращающий это значение. Ну и посмотрите в консоли что приходит в data.

Comment: Скриншоты из контроллера

Comment: в любой непонятной ситуации делай `console.log(data);`, в 90% случаев это приводит к возгласу "б**" и вопрос отпадает. в остальных 9% случаяев аналогичный эффект дает `print_r($whatever_you_send);`... вы сделали эти 2 пункта? поделитесь результатами с нами, если хотите конструктива ))

Comment: контроллер возвращать должен наследников `ActionResult` в данном случае нам скорее нужен `JsonResult`, что такое `Products`  у вас?

Comment: Такой код просто наводит на сомнения. У Вас метод контроллера возвращает `Products`, понимаете? Ни `ActionResult` и ни `JsonResult`, а просто `Products`. Вы пытаетесь получить `data.Price`, но в результате у Вас балалайка. Сделайте `console.log(data)` - посмотрите, что у Вас там в принципе `undefined` и поменяйте код в соответствии с некоторыми правилами.  На крайний случай почитайте про `MVC` и `Ajax` и `jQuery`

Answer (score 2):

Контроллер:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Editproducts(int id)
{       
    Products SenMes = null;
    using (DBEntities bd = new DBEntities())
        Products SenMes = bd.Products.Find(id);
    return Json(SenMes);
}
```

Если нужно вернуть не все поля SenMes, а только конкретные:

```
return Json(new { Id=SenMes.Id, Price=SenMes.Price });
```